# Systemd - echo command does not work inside shell script

Tags: bash, systemd

I have this service script:

```
[Unit]
Description=Description

[Service]
Type=simple

EnvironmentFile=/usr/local/etc/env.conf
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/script.sh
User=my_user
Group=my_user

StandardOutput=journal
StandardError=journal

Restart=on-failure
RestartPreventExitStatus=13
RestartSec=10s

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

File script.sh looks as follow:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "BOOM #1";

# /home/my_user/script.py

echo "BOOM #2";
```

File script.py looks as follow:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

print "BOOM #P"
```

The problem is I do not see anything in journalctl if python script is commented. If I uncomment python script I will see in journalctl following lines:

```
BOOM #1

BOOM #P
```

I am suspecting that it might be some kind of buffering issue, but this is my guess. Any hint why to do to actually see echoes?

Comment: Your python script is invalid; `echo` is not a built-in in python. Did you mean `print`?

Comment: Whether the Python script is or is not commented can have no effect on whether "BOOM #1" is flushed, as it's written to the process's stdout before the Python script is ever started. Did you really reproduce the bug with the _exact_ code given here? If you had an `exec` command in your Python command line, this would make much more sense. :)

Comment: Yes, my bad, it supposed to be print in python. I was in haste. Python script in ExecStart would be better that's true, but I have some problems with interpreting environmental variables, while in shell I can do extra exports to set everything for a python.

Comment: And actually don't know why but if I uncomment python scripts BOOM #1 is printed if I do not uncomment it, shell scripts end up with 'success' state but nothing is in the logs.

Comment: change `ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/script.sh` to `ExecStart=/bin/sh -c '/usr/local/bin/script.sh'`